Mongodb / atlas search: Many to Many relationship with huge collections
im modeling an app where user can stamps (up to 100 000 stamps).
I created the following  collections:
users:
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "xxx"
    },
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    ...
}

stamps:
{
    "_id": {
       "$oid": "ccc"
    },
    "searchTags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
    ...
}

users_stamps
{
    "_id": {
        "user": {
            "$oid": "xxx"
        },
       "stamp": {
            "$oid": "ccc"
        }
    },
    "searchTags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
}

My goal is to allow users to search stamps in their collection by name (sql equilvalent: "SELECT * FROM stamps WHERE name LIKE "%uru%" and id IN (SELECT stamp_id FROM user_stamps WHERE user_id="xxx")".
I added "searchTags" in users_stamps  documents to make fast indexed search on this field.(tried with lookup + condition + filter + limit = too slow as i need to do the lookup on first stage).
Im not sure about this approach so i have some questions:

Is it ok to do so as when user search for a stamp, i query stamps or users_stamps depending on user request ?
As searchTags is duplicated, is it best to create a DB trigger to update users_stamps each time a stamp is updated (rarely updated) ?
Is this approach good enough for 10k users (10k * 100k stamps= 1billion records on users_stamps) ?

Thanks
